# Generic C# class with limited types to some interface is not implementing other interface with member of the first one

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I'got a problem with understanding why having such class:

```
public class Section<T> : ISection 
    where T : ISectionItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public LinkedList<T> Items { get; set; }
}
```

implementing such interface:

```
public interface ISection
{
    string Title { get; set; }
    LinkedList<ISectionItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

I get compiler error saying:

```
Error   1   
'JobTracker.Model.CV.Section<T>' does not implement interface member 
'JobTracker.Model.CV.ISection.Items'. 
'JobTracker.Model.CV.Section<T>.Items' cannot implement 
'JobTracker.Model.CV.ISection.Items' 
because it does not have the matching return type of
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<JobTracker.Model.CV.ISectionItem>'.
```

It should be possible, as T is guaranteed to be of type `ISectionItem`. One of possible solutions problably would be to create addidiotional to or replace `ISection` with generic `ISection<T>`, but I dont know how it will behave when I will want to use it with Xaml. Is there any to let know the compiler that the interface meets the requirements?

EDIT1: Changed `IEnumerable` to `LinkedList` in `ISection` as it was a bad concept and answers focus a bit aside from topic I was the most interested in.

EDIT2: My question was more directed on why T implementing `ISectionItem` is not allowed, but I noticed how stupid I was. Interface `ISection` allows usage of several different classes implementing `ISectionItem` in one list `Section<T>` does not.

Guys, both Your answers are correct but I will mark Olivier's as an answer as it alos shows the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you access `Items` through the interface it would be possible to assign it a collection not being a `LinkedList<T>`, which would result in an error. Since `Items` also has a setter, it cannot be anything but `IEnumerable<T>`; however, you can implement it like this

```
private LinkedList<T> _items;
public IEnumerable<T> Items {
    get { return _items; }
    set {
        var linkedList = value as LinkedList<T>;
        if (linkedList != null) {
            _items = linkedList;
        } else {
            _items = new LinkedList<T>(value);
        }
    }
}
```

For this to work, you have to change the interface to:

```
public interface ISection<T>
    where T : ISectionItem
{
    string Title { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<T> Items { get; set; }
}
```

and to declare the class like this

```
public class Section<T> : ISection<T> 
    where T : ISectionItem
{
    ...
}
```

---

Your **edit** does not solve the problem. Through your class you can assign a `LinkedList<T>` of any `T` implementing `ISectionItem`; however your interface allows you to add a `ISectionItem` different from `T`.

```
class DerivedA : ISectionItem
{
    ...
}

class DerivedB : ISectionItem
{
    ...
}
```

```
ISection s = new Section<DerivedA>();
s.AddLast(new DerivedB()); // The collection in `s` is a `LinkedList<DerivedA>` boom!
```

---

The moral of the story is that the inheritance of the collection items (or in general: of the generic type parameters of some type) does NOT define the inheritance of the collection.

Let's `T'` derive from `T`.

`Collection<T'>` derives from `Collection<T>` ==> **false!**

The two collections are just two different collections not having any assignment compatibility.

Comment: Nope, can't be `IEnumerable<T>`, has to be `IEnumerable<ISectionItem>`

Comment: Yes. We need to add the generic type parameter to the interface as well to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

It **doesn't** meet the requirements.

Consider the following

```
Section<ItemX> xSection = new Section<ItemX>;
//xSection.Items = BindingList<ISectionItem>();
ISection xISection = xSection;
xISection.Items = BindingList<ISectionItem>();
```

The contract from the interface is that `Items` can be assigned to *any* collection of `ISectionItem`.

Comment: Ok, You're right, but what if I change from `IEnumerable` to `LinkedList` in the `ISection`? Why it's still not enough?

Answer (score 0):

If you could make your `Items` interface property read-only, the simplest route seems to be to add an explicit interface implementation as an overload:

```
public interface ISection
{
    string Title { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<ISectionItem> Items { get; }
}

public class Section<T> : ISection 
    where T : ISectionItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public LinkedList<T> Items { get; set; }

    IEnumerable<ISectionItem> ISection.Items
    {
        get {return Items.Cast<ISectionItem>();}
    }
}
```